# Помогите решить задачу по JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Дан инпут, в который можно ввести число. Сделайте так, чтобы при вводе числа в этот инпут и потери фокуса на странице искался чекбокс с таким номером и становился отмеченным, а остальные чекбоксы становились неотмеченными.

Comment: Вы таки продолжаете писать задания без намёка на попытки его решения самостоятельно

Comment: Уиии, в наше время "помогите" === "сделайте за меня".

Comment: В чем сложности с выполнением задачи?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("input[type='number']").blur(function () {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false).eq($(this).val()-1).prop('checked', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=number min=1><br>
<input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox><input type=checkbox>
```

Comment: @Other, вообще, вопрос можно было превратить в хороший, изменив на "как снять все чекбоксы в группе и отметить только один из них" ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79401/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-other).

Answer (score 0):

Если номер чекбокса - в его id(например, id="check_1") и класс всех чекбоксов class="check", тогда:

```
$('input').on('blur',function(event){
 var num=$(this).val();
 var id='check_'+num;
 $('.check').each(function(){
  (this).checked(false);
 });
 $(id).checked(true);
});
```

Comment: Вы тестировали написанный вами код? Вместо `(this)`, я так подозреваю, должно быть `$(this)`, вместо `checked(false)` - `prop("checked", false)`.

Comment: Метод `prop`, кстати, умеет работать с коллекцией, так что `.each` тут излишен.